# Apache ignite listening to state change of objects in local nodes

Tags: ignite

I am investigating a use case where ignite has to listen to changes of a property of an object in the data grid and do some operations on that object. For performance, I want the processing to be done on the same node where the data is.

- How can I get an event when the property of a object has changed to a specific value (eg. Object '`X`' has a property '`state`' which is set to '`scheduled`' from '`created`') and make sure that only events are taken from the node where the object lives in?
- How can I make sure that when I got the event and start processing it, nobody else changes the object (only read is allowed) until processing is finished (in other words, a transaction starts as soon as the event is picked up)?
- How can I make sure that the processing code is deployed to all nodes (processing is stateless) and that it only operates on local data (without having a hard link between data object and code, in other words, if the processing code is updated in the future, the objects stay untouched)

What I got from the docs is the following:

```
// Local listener that listenes to local events.
IgnitePredicate<CacheEvent> locLsnr = evt -> {


  // CODE

  return result;
};

// Subscribe to specified cache events occuring on local node.
ignite.events().localListen(locLsnr,
  EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT);
```

- In the `CODE` block; I have to check for a `state` change on '`evt.newValue()`', can't that be done earlier? Ie. as a paremeter to localListen somehow?
- In the `CODE` block, is the Object locked until I return the result? In other words, is it in here that I am sure nobody can changes the object and that I can safely change my Object? IMO it is a strange place to do that in a 'Predicate' definition and not in a handler class.

Sven

Answer (score 2):

Sven,

Your code looks correct and should work as you expect. Answering your questions:

- Event listener is called right after the value is updated, so I think it's OK to check the field you're interested in inside the listener. If the field is not changed, just return right away.
- The object is locked, because listener is called inside the sync block for the entry. You can modify the same object, but I would not recommend to execute any sync operations like cache updates inside the listener because it's error-prone and can affect performance. You should do this asynchronously, so that the lock is released as soon as possible.

Comment: For your last answer: how should the cache update be done then asynchronously? The object really may not change in between...

Comment: @Sven, if you want to update two or more cache values atomically, you should not use events, just open a transaction and do all cache operations inside it. If you can't start a transaction on client side for some reason, send a closure to the proper server node (https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/collocate-compute-and-data) and run the transaction there.

Comment: The use case is as follows: state change of object, means on the grid, action has to be taken by executing code (ie. event based, no clients involved). While code is executed, nothing should change the object anymore until execution has stopped and object is updated. How can I do this without using events? Do you mean using an async affinityRun from within the listener on the object?

Comment: @Sven Who initiates the initial update of the object?

Comment: Some random client of the grid via a request coming from the frontend (eg. webserver)

Comment: @Sven, so why don't just start a transaction on this client and update both values atomically? Refer to this page for details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/transactions

Comment: We want to use an event driven architecture where everything is loosely coupled. Starting a transaction on the client means we have to work synchronously and wait for immediate feedback. This is not always possible, since further processing could take a long time on some backend system with which we have to integrate.